# Responsive design and advertising

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design

This is my first attempt at creating a responsive website.

So, I have stylesheets loading depending on the size of device, meaning that some divs may or may not be visible.

One problem that I've encountered is that on mobiles I don't want to show a panel that has content and advertising. The issue I have is that I am still building that panel and making the mobile visitors download it but not displaying it. It's still being loaded and I'm being credited for it, but can't be clicked/seen and I'll have my hand slapped.

So, how do I only load ads (let's say an iframe or javascript) if the div is to be visible? Or even better maybe only load a complete div/panel if it's visible?

Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Check with JS if it is visible and load it.. have you tried that?

Comment: I've noticed this too as a problem with responsive design CSS. I'm not concerned about advertising, just did that mobile devices will load large size assets such as images or stylesheets which they then do not display.

Comment: Putvande is probably along the right path.  Whatever your solution, keep in mind that responsive design by definition responds to changes in the window size.  So you could have a desktop that starts off narrow and has the mobile view, but later resizes and gets the full view.  If you only check on page load whether it's visible it breaks down.  So in addition to checking on load you may want to check any time the window resizes.  What you end up with is effectively lazy loading.

Comment: JavaScript is probably your best bet. In J query, it would be like " if ($('#element_id').is(':visible')){ display_ad(); }". Plus a check on resize as Nelson suggests

Comment: This is a widely discussed topic on the responsive design front, you should look at this resources: [Conditionally load js based on media query](http://responsivedesign.is/develop/javascript/conditionally-load-javascript-based-on-media-query), [Enquire Js](http://css-tricks.com/enquire-js-media-query-callbacks-in-javascript/) or [Response Js](http://responsejs.com/)

Comment: If you're using php, try https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect. Then you can just not load it at all, no images, no scripts, nothing.